# nodejs server is not defined

Tags: node.js, ubuntu-18.04

i will use **nodemon start** command but getting error. Can you help me?

> ReferenceError: server is not defined

### app.js

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var other = require('./others');


var app = express();

app.get('/index', other.index);
app.get('/', other.index);

server.listen(8006);
```

### others.js

```
var path = require('path');

module.exports.index = function(req, res)
{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
}
```

Comment: Please share your package.json (scripts > start)

Comment: It's `app.listen(8006)` not `server.listen(8006)`;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The variable `server` is not defined in your code.

It should be `app.listen(8006)`

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo in line 4. Your module name is 'other'. So while importing the module you should use

```
var other = require('./other');
```

Instead, you are using

```
var other = require('./others'); // change others to other
```

Your final **app.js** should be looks like

```
var fs = require('fs');
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var other = require('./other');


var app = express();

app.get('/index', other.index);
app.get('/', other.index);

app.listen(8006);
```

Make sure you installed the express module in your project.